# Issues with Android 4.3 Emulator in Xamarin Studio

Tags: android, emulation, xamarin

I use Xamarin Studio 4.0.12 and want to test my App with a Android 4.3 Emulator, but it doesn't work. It works with the other Android Version Emulators(2.2 - 4.0).
This is the application output:

```
[libc] bionic/libc/upstream-netbsd/libc/stdlib/bsearch.c:70: bsearch: assertion "key != NULL" failed
[mono-rt] Stacktrace:
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt] =================================================================
[mono-rt] Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
[mono-rt] a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
[mono-rt] used by your application.
[mono-rt] =================================================================
[mono-rt]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Download Android SDK 22.0 It would be supproted for all Android Version Outputs..And also that SDK includes with All versions of Android emulators.